# xib shows blank box even we have many view and other designing in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, xcode10

I am using xib and it just shows blank square box even I have done designing and added many views.

Please check attached image no matter its huge designing or just 1 - 2 labels it shows the only square box. 
but if I run it will woks perfectly in the device.

My Xcode version is 10.2.1.
[image]

Comment: I think issue is with rendering. have you get any error or warning in xcode. and also check Editor-> Refresh all view

Comment: @JaydeepVyas there is no error and in editor-> Refactor shows all option is unclickable.

Comment: can you please post your nib (or any nib that have proble )file via drop box or any other link so i can see the issue

Comment: I have other macbook on that its working fine but on this xcode creating problem

Comment: you can try to create another xib check it will look ok, if yes than copy your view paste it new xib check black box appear or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following options to debug this issue:

1. Drag the main view to increase its size and give it some background color which can be seen easily(like red).
2. Try populating the labels with text in the XIB so that they take up some space and expand the views dependent on them.
3. Give height constraints to all the views to check if they are visible.